# How do I restore the yaboot bootloader screen after OS X install?

Tags: yaboot

I had to reinstall OS X Tiger to the first partition, but reinstalling it modified my boot loader and I no longer had access to the yaboot choice menu.

Answer (score 2):

I shut down the iMac and started it up holding down the option key (Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> for PC keyboard) and selected my linux partition that showed up in order to boot it.

I got to Ubuntu 12.04.1 for PowerPC, started Terminal and did `sudo su` and entered my password and then just ran `ybin` which fixed everything.

Now I have the yaboot bootloader back when I start the Mac.